# $[0,1)\times[0,1)$ (lower limit topology) is a regular, but not a normal topological space

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, separation-axioms, product-space, sorgenfrey-line

Let $X=[0,1)\times[0,1)$, $\tau$ its topology with base $$\beta = \{ [a,b)\times[c,d): 0 \leq a < b \leq 1,  0 \leq c < d \leq 1 \}\;.$$ Please help me prove, that it is regular, but not a normal topological space.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HINTS: For regularity, first prove that $\beta$ is a base for $\tau$ consisting of clopen (i.e., both closed and open) sets; regularity of $X$ follows immediately. For non-normality, let $D=\{\langle x,1-x\rangle:x\in[0,1)\}$; you can easily prove that $D$ is a closed, discrete subset of $X$. Let $H=\{\langle x,1-x\rangle\in D:x\in\Bbb Q\}$, and let $K=D\setminus H$; then $H$ and $K$ are disjoint closed subsets of $X$ that cannot be separated by disjoint open sets. For this part you’ll probably want the Baire category theorem.

Comment: I believe one could also apply Jone's Lemma to show non-normality:  If $X$ contains a dense set $D$ and a closed, relatively discrete subspace $S$ with $|S|\ge 2^{|D|}$, then $X$ is not normal. c.f Willard *General Topology*. pg. 100.

Comment: @David: True. (For some reason I always forget about Jones’ Lemma.)

Comment: Sorry, but can you please explain why X is regular. Thanks in advance

Comment: @user31497: Which part are you having trouble with? Seeing that each member of $\beta$ is closed as well as open? Or seeing why that implies regularity?

Comment: I think the second.

Comment: @user31497: Let $x\in X$, and let $F$ be a closed set in $X$ not containing $x$. Then $X\setminus F$ is an open set containing $x$, so there is some $B\in\beta$ such that $x\in B\subseteq X\setminus F$. $B$ is closed as well as open, so $B$ and $X\setminus B$ are disjoint open sets with $x\in B$ and $F\subseteq X\setminus B$. Does that help?

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott Why $D$ is discrete?

Comment: @Brian M. Scott  Dear Brian, I was also thinking about the example $H$ which is the set of rational points in the line $D=\{x+y=1\}$, and the set $D-H$. I wasn't able to show they cannot be separated by disjoint open sets. Can you provide some details about this? For example how Baire's theorem can be applied here? Thanks!

Comment: @Brian M. Scott Dear Brian, now I understand. Thanks for your answer (in 2012) !

Comment: @Yuval: You’re welcome (and I’m glad that you were able to sort it out for yourself).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I am very much interested in the role of Baire theorem to reject the existence of separation, thanks in advance.

Comment: @Riaz: The details are a bit too long for a comment, but you can find them in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276742/proof-that-sorgenfrey-plane-is-not-normal-using-points-x-%C3%97-x) and my answer to it, and in the second bullet point in [this post](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/2009/10/01/a-short-note-about-the-sorgenfrey-line/) at **Dan Ma’s Topology Blog**.