# Prove this space is not T4 space

Tags: general-topology

Note that R : the set of real numbers, Q : the set of rational numbers.
Let P={[a,b)x[c,d) | a,b,c,d in R} and T be a topology generated by a basis P. Let Z be a topological space with the topology T and Y={(x, y) | x+y=1} be a subspace of Z.
Define A={(x,y) in Y | (x,y) in QxQ} and B=Y-A.

Prove the space Z is not T4-space following these steps.
__step1 : prove that A and B are closed.
__step2 : prove that two distinct open sets U, V that covers A and B, respectively, does not exist.
__step3 : From these steps, we have Z is not T4.

Comment: Note that $Y$ is closed and discrete.

Answer (score 1):

The space $Z$ is the [Sorgenfrey plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorgenfrey_plane), a well-known example in topology. [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276742/proof-that-sorgenfrey-plane-is-not-normal-using-points-x-x) and my answer to it give a proof that it is not normal using the anti-diagonal $D=\{\langle x,-x\rangle:x\in\Bbb R\}$ instead of the parallel line $Y$: the closed sets $A=\{\langle q,-q\rangle:q\in\Bbb Q\}$ and $D\setminus A$ cannot be separated by disjoint open sets. With very minor modifications the same proof will work for your problem as well.