# Showing that the Sorgenfrey plane is not normal. Munkres Exercise 9 from Section 31.

Tags: general-topology

Let $L$ be the anti-diagonal of $\Bbb R_\ell^2$, $D=\Bbb Q^2$, $A=L\cap D$ and $B=L\setminus D$ and suppose $V$ is an open set of $X$ containing $B$.

For each $n\in\Bbb N_+$ we define
$$K_n=\{x\in[0,1]\setminus\Bbb Q:\exists n [x,x+1/n)\times [-x,-x+1/n)\subseteq V\}.$$

For part (a) it's see to see that $\bigcup K_n=[0,1]\setminus\Bbb Q$

Part of this question has been answered here: [Proof that Sorgenfrey plane is not normal using points x × (-x)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276742/proof-that-sorgenfrey-plane-is-not-normal-using-points-x-%C3%97-x).

However, I'm stuck on a different part of the problem, namely (b).  This part refers to Exercise 5 of Section 27.  It states, that if $X$ is compact, Hausdorff and $\{A_n\}$ is a family of closed sets with empty interior, then $\bigcup A_n$ has empty interior.

The idea is to use the contrpositive of this statement to show that there is a $\overline K_n$ that contains an open interval.  From part (a) we see that $\overline{\bigcup K_n}=[0,1]$, but we are considering $\bigcup\overline K_n$.  In general, $\bigcup\overline K_n\subseteq\overline{\bigcup K_n}$.  How do we know that $\bigcup\overline K_n$ contains an open interval?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: For your countable collection of closed sets use

$$\{\operatorname{cl}K_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\}\cup\big\{\{x\}:x\in\Bbb Q\cap[0,1]\big\}\;.$$