# Regular topological spaces need not to be normal

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, separation-axioms, sorgenfrey-line

I was looking for a counterexample for the following statement:

"A regular topological space need not to be normal."

I don't understand how to use the lemma to prove Theorem 7: http://fac.hsu.edu/worth/topology/separate.html

> *Lemma.* Suppose $X$ is a topological space that is normal and has a countable subset whose closure is the whole space. If $E$ is an uncountable subset of $X$, then $E$ has a limit point.
>
> **Theorem 7.** $T_3$ does not imply $T_4$ and regular does not imply normal.
>
> *Proof.* Let $X$ be the real line. Let $B = \{[a, b)\}$. $B$ is a basis for a topology for $X$. The lemma can be used to show that, though it is regular, $X \times X$ is not normal.

Thank you!

Comment: Probably this post might be useful for you: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145621/regular-but-not-a-normal-topological-space

Comment: Am I the only one for whom proof of Theorem 7 from the link in the post displays a strange character: "X þ X"? Is it supposed to be product; $X\times X$?

Comment: @Martin: I also see a thorn (þ), and yes, it’s supposed to be $X\times X$.

Answer (score 4):

The lemma in question says that if $X$ is a separable, normal space, and $E\subseteq X$ is uncountable, then $E$ has a limit point. Since a subset of $X$ has no limit point if and only if it is closed and discrete, this amounts to saying that every closed, discrete subset of a separable, normal space is countable. Unfortunately, this is not quite correct. What *is* true is that if $C$ is a closed, discrete subset of a separable, normal space, then $|\wp(C)|\le 2^\omega=\mathfrak{c}$. This is Jones’s lemma, and you can find a proof [here](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/2012/07/31/jones-lemma/). (The version that you found is equivalent to Jones’s lemma only if the [continuum hypothesis  ($\mathsf{CH}$)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis) holds;  $\mathsf{CH}$ is consistent with the usual axioms of set theory, but so is its negation.)

Now let $X$ be the space described in the partial proof of Theorem $7$; this space is known as the [Sorgenfrey line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lower_limit_topology) or reals with the lower limit topology. Let $D=\{\langle x,-x\rangle:x\in X\}$, the ‘reverse diagonal’ in the plane. It’s easy to check that $D$ is closed and discrete in $X\times X$. (E.g., for discreteness note that $[x,x+1)\times[-x,-x+1)$ is an open nbhd of $\langle x,-x\rangle$ that contains no other point of $D$.) Clearly $|D|=|\Bbb R|=2^\omega$, so by [Cantor’s theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor's_theorem) $|\wp(D)|>2^\omega$.

$\Bbb Q\times\Bbb Q$ is a countable dense subset of $X\times X$ in the product Sorgenfrey topology, since every non-empty open set in $X\times X$ contains a non-empty set that is open in the Euclidean topology on $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$. Thus, $X\times X$ is separable, and by Jones’s lemma it cannot be normal. My answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145621/0-1-times0-1-lower-limit-topology-is-a-regular-but-not-a-normal-topolog) indicates why $X\times X$ is regular (indeed, Tikhonov).

Comment: Thank you, it's clear now!

Comment: @nbayo: You’re welcome!